# Проблема с присваиванием строки JTextField'y

Tags: java, swing

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не для всех строк можно присвоить значение переменной, если поставить строке ограничение такого вида:

```
jTextField.setText("" + varText);
jTextField.setDocument(new PlainDocument() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        if (getLength() < 10) {
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }
});
```

Приходится для этих строк убирать ограничение. Как исправить эту проблему? И как можно сочетать присвоение переменной строке и ограничение?

Comment: Про какую переменную речь, и для какой конкретной строки что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Если честно какие то чудеса происходят. переменная поступает из другого окна, из выделенной строки пользователем в таблице. Хочу сделать редактирование данных в таблице, в новом окне с текстовыми полями для редактирования данных сначала показываются имеющиеся данные. Если убрать ограничения для ввода в текстовые поля, не все данные меняются

Comment: Стоит добавить полный пример кода, воспроизводящего проблему, в вопросу. Вместо и с конкретным примером строки. На данный момент не очень понятно что, где и как.

Comment: Если вы в таком порядке и вызываете, то установка нового `Document` затирает значение, положенное через `setText`, т.к. текст хранится в документе.